# Not Working: Allow Guest Checkout = No

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, guest-checkout, guest

I'm using Magento 2.4.3. For some reason, guest checkout is still allowed, even after selecting the Allow Guest Checkout = No setting in the backend. It doesn't show the "Guest checkout is disabled" message anymore. It was working for a while, and then, it seemed to randomly stop working. I have tried changing the setting to *Yes* and then back to *No* and then re-indexing and clearing the cache, but guest checkout is still allowed. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Try checking the configurations in all store views scope as that field has that feasibility for store views, and try checking in browsers incognito mode also one time.Thanks

Comment: The configuration for all store views has also been changed between the different options without success. Incognito mode still has the same result.

Answer (score 1):

still no answer to this?  Finding myself in a similar situation at the moment.